# Load webpage in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm just wondering how I can load a webpage within nodejs, I've been searching for 2 days and I can't find anything. Either I'm using the wrong search terms or I'm just not looking for what I actually need.

I need to open a link to authenticate an account and I've retrieved the URL that I need to open but I'm not sure how. I've tried http.request but it mustn't be loading the page as when I check if the account has been verified it hasn't.

How would I go about this?

Thanks (Sorry for nooby question and bad formatting)

Buck

P.S Oops I wrote it in such a hurry I forgot to add the snippet of my code

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
    host: Host, //Both variables defined earlier in the code this is just a snippet of the http.request part
    path: Path
};

callback = function(response) {
    var string = '';

response.on('data', function (blob) {
    string += blob;
});

response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(string);
    });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

It just returns

```
 ['R޾�\s۝�V������T��:�I����$��v�* �*�;�* P���q�ܠ���5�E!9��I���v��r��� �CmO����q��<�>���&�趩�C��i�&��a��q�(��1a4I^XvLe�T˔�|��M�3�EA!نY\0�h�R��#r�b�a��Yr��z��1аB
```

Even when I try

```
console.log(string.toString('utf8'));
```

Comment: http.request will send a request for files, to authenticate you might also need to send more requests that is run by the javascript files you retrieve. My advice is to go to the site check in chrome inspection mode what kind of requests are sent to the server for authentication and write a script for those.

Comment: "I've tried http.request" — That's a perfectly fine way to do it. There isn't enough information in your question to determine why it isn't working. You need to provide a [mcve]. You need to look at the response you get.

Comment: I'm really sorry guys, I was in such a hurry to write it I forgot to include my code. Really sorry again guys :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find what the problem was and fix it,

Further above in my code I had not declared an important variable properly.

http.request works perfectly